# How to refresh data within an SSAS model

Tags: model, ssas, powerbi

I'm in Visual Studio working on a model.

The model is using a view. I made a change to a column in this view but even if I go into Edit Table Properties and click on "REFRESH PREVIEW", it still shows the old data for this column.

It's a timestamp column that I changed to date only.

If I run the view on the SQL Server, I can see that it's working correctly.

How can I refresh the table within my model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Tabular model in Visual Studio is your workspace database.  Doing the processing from within Visual Studio/SSDT will show changes in the source data reflected there.  On the top menu, go to **Model** > **Process** > and select the object (table, partitions, all) that you want to do.  After this, you can verify that your workspace database was processed in SSMS.  To do this, connect to SSAS through SSMS and find the workspace database.  This will be the database with the same name as well as your user name and a GUID appended to it.  Right click this and select **Properties**.  Find the **Last Processed** field and verify that the timestamp here matches the time you processed it.  There are a number of ways to process the deployed model.  Perhaps the easiest being from SSMS.  This can be done by right-clicking the deployed model (without your username/GUID), and selecting **Process Database** and then choosing the type of processing to perform.  You can also do this on individual tables and partitions through SSMS in the same manner.